# How to filter out Distinct objects of a Particular subtype from a List of super type with Streams

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, distinct, instanceof

I would like to create a Java stream that will collect only elements that are `instanceof` class `A` and at the same time are distinct by `x`.

I am using Java 8.

What I have in the beginning is a `List` of instances of class `C`.

```
Class A extends B{
   int x;
}

Class B extends C{

}

Class C(){

}
```

but other classes also extend class C.

What I did so far:

```
List<C> input = ...; 
List<C> result = input.stream()
    .filter(r -> r instanceof A)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And this works fine however for the first part.

However, I would like to compare all elements and get a `List` of distinct objects (compare by value of `int x`).

Comment: You have to override `equals` and `hashCode` in you class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a method that would expect an instance of target class [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) in order to filter out any subtype of `C` from the source list.

Note that would work only if `equals/hashCode` contract was properly implemented by each subclass.

```
public static <T extends C> List<T> getItemsOfType(List<C> source,
                                                   Class<T> itemClass) {
    return source.stream()
        .filter(item -> itemClass.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())) // ensures that this element can be safely casted to the target type
        .map(itemClass::cast) // casting to the type T
        .distinct()           // ensures uniqueness of elements according to `equals/hashCode` implementation of the type T
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<C> input = List.of(new A(1), new D(), new A(3));
    List<A> result = getItemsOfType(input, A.class);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[A{x=1}, A{x=3}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not fully understand part of it, but after minor changes it works just as I wanted for both easy and more complex problem.

Comment: @zaoras I've improved the code and provided a demo with a dummy `C` and `D` classes.

Comment: This answer may be better for the example from my post, but in my code I also have a second, harder case where I need to compare objects of type A by a single property that is of type of another class(which has equals/hc implemented), but cannot compare them by class A equals/hc, so I will stick to the previous answer. Thanks for update tho.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should override `hashCode` and `equals` of your `class A` to define equality.

A handy way is to use `@EqualsAndHashCode` provided by `Project lombok` to generate `hashCode` and `equals` implementations from the fields of your object.

Try this

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode 
class A extends B {
   int x;
}
```

And then, just simply use `stream().distinct()` to make it.

```java
List<C> result = input.stream()
    .filter(r -> r instanceof A)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

reference https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode

Comment: Ok, and lets say that instead of int x, I have object of another class D? That class D has both hashcode and equals implemented, do you think this solution would still work?

Comment: Yes. If you could define the equality well.